# Защита базы данных Firebird

Tags: база-данных, шифрование, firebird, защита

Здравствуйте! У меня возник вопрос по защите базы данных Firebird (3.0.2).
Firebird не имеет встроенного шифрования, а плагины для шифрования находил только платные, которые стоят очень дорого. Буду благодарен любому совету.
Гуглил и находил идеи с шифрованным контейнером (диском). Но так как программа пишется под заказ, тут появляются лицензионные ограничения на распространение ПО для шифрования вместе со своей программой.

Программа (на C#) работает с медицинской базой данных, поэтому защита БД необходима.
Изначально я рассматривал вариант с MySQL, но пришлось отказаться от этой СУБД из-за лицензионных ограничений, хотя она мне понравилась больше, чем Firebird.

Также рассмотрю предложения по смене СУБД, главное, чтобы были встроенные средства шифрования, СУБД являлась бесплатной и можно было использовать в коммерческих целях бесплатно (по этой причине и выбрал Firebird).
Спасибо.

Comment: А чем именно не устраивает лицензия MySQL? Вроде там проблема с GPL возникает, только если Вы встраиваете их бинарники в свою программу.
Ну а по сути вопроса - PostgreSQL.

Comment: @Yaant, добрый день! Как раз бинарники и нужно было встраивать, т.е. включать в установщик и переносить со своей программой. А насчет PostgreSQL спасибо.